# How can you add text to a string and then save and print it on the screen in Kaboom.js?

Tags: javascript, game-development, kaboom

Kia ora everyone!

I'm trying to make my own input system in Kaboom.js by adding functions like the below and adding each key to a string called `i` (short for input).

`keyPress("j", () => { i.concat("j"); });`

Then, I try and console.log `i`. (i do it like `console.log(i);`) And for some reason I get nothing. I think it's because it's not logging an update to the string?

Is there a better method I can use, and what is wrong with my program?

Ngā mihi
Florence

Answer (score 0):

If your big long string is called inputString then something like this ought to come close:

```
let inputString = "";
k.onKeyPress("a", event => {
   inputString.concat("a");
   console.info(inputString);
   console.info(event);
});
```

Rather than copy this out for every different key you're probably best trying to catch all keypresses and then check the properties of the `event` to determine if it's a relevant key, not an arrow key etc..